# How to solve the error of too many arguments for method sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a spark select query for the dataframe as follows :

**val ans = spark.sql(Select empname,count (visa_class) as Approved_Visa from visa group by empname order by Approved_Visa DESC Limit 10)**

*I get the following error : too many arguments for method sql (sql text string)org.apache.spark.sql.dataframe*

Comment: wrap the query with the quote sign "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like syntax error. You need to provide SQL statement in quotes.
Example:

```
val ans = spark.sql("select * from table")
```